# iOS Overlay View - Masking UITableViewController with a view is partially masking UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, mask

iPhone - 5.1(9B176)

I have been encountering inconsistent behaviour in overlaying a mask view on top of a UITableViewController as shown in picture below. Anyone encountered this behaviour, if yes, please suggest any solutions used?

[image: Partially masked view on top of UITableViewController]

Below is the code i have used to add mask view:

```
//Add the overlay view.
if(ovController == nil) {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"overlayVC";
    ovController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}

CGFloat yaxis = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;

CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, yaxis, width, height);
ovController.view.frame = frame;
ovController.view.alpha = 0.85;
ovController.delegate = self;

UIView *aboveView = self.parentViewController.view;

[self.tableView insertSubview:ovController.view aboveSubview:aboveView];
```

I have also tried

```
`[self.tableView insertSubview:ovController.view aboveSubview:self.tableView]`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi use something like below code

```
-(void) showLoadingView {

//NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> loading view Landscape right ");
if (loadView == nil) {
    loadView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 480.0)];
    loadView.opaque = NO;
    loadView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //loadView.alpha = 0.8;

    viewBack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(95, 230, 130, 40)];
    viewBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    viewBack.alpha = 0.7f;
    viewBack.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    viewBack.layer.cornerRadius = 8; 

    spinningWheel = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0, 5.0, 30.0, 30.0)];
    [spinningWheel startAnimating];
    //        spinningWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    [viewBack addSubview:spinningWheel];
    [spinningWheel release];        

    UILabel *lblLoading = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(23, 6, 110, 25)];
    lblLoading.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblLoading.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:16.0];
    lblLoading.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    lblLoading.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    lblLoading.text = @"Loading...";
    [viewBack addSubview:lblLoading];
    [loadView addSubview:viewBack];
}    

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    loadView.frame = iphoneFrame;
    viewBack.frame = loadiPhone;        
}
else
{
    loadView.frame = ipadFrame;  
    viewBack.frame = loadiPad;
}

[self.window addSubview:loadView];
```

}

-(void) hideLoadingView {

```
[loadView removeFromSuperview];
```

}

declare this methods in you APPdelegate class so you can call it from any view in your code.

here i have set a view over the window not in view this surelu solve your problem!!!!

Comment: Thanks Neel. Part of Your solution worked. But i need a masked view with some other purpose as well. Adding subview to window worked. 

    [[appDelegate window] addSubview:ovController.view];

However i am still wondering why in case of UITableViewController inserting a subview on top of a table view is not working as expected.

Comment: don't know exact reason but you can do this by inserting table and loading view in viewcontroller... i think you got my point